# Counter Number of Times in State

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to add a column which tells me the iteration count of how many times we've been in a state, ordered by date.

We see we're in state 1 for the first time, state 2 for the first time, then BACK to state 1 (iteration is now 2), the Iteration stays the same until we change state.

I'd like to calculate column 'Iteration'

Thanks in advance if anyone can help!

*edit: changed column name to State from Group to avoid confusion

| Date | State | Iteration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-01-02 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-01-03 | 2 | 1 |
| 2021-01-04 | 1 | 2 |
| 2021-01-06 | 1 | 2 |
| 2021-01-07 | 1 | 2 |
| 2021-01-08 | 2 | 2 |
| 2021-01-09 | 2 | 2 |
| 2021-01-10 | 3 | 1 |
| 2021-01-11 | 3 | 1 |

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih I think the expected results are the table that is shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method would be to use `LAG` to see if the value has changed, and if it has, increment the counter, then do a windowed sum per group:

```sql
WITH Lags AS(
    SELECT [Date],
           [Group], --GROUP is a reserved keyword, and should not be used for object names
           CASE [Group] WHEN LAG([Group]) OVER (ORDER BY [date]) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Increment --GROUP is a reserved keyword, and should not be used for object names
    FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(date,'20210101'),1),
                (CONVERT(date,'20210102'),1),
                (CONVERT(date,'20210103'),2),
                (CONVERT(date,'20210104'),1),
                (CONVERT(date,'20210106'),1),
                (CONVERT(date,'20210107'),1),
                (CONVERT(date,'20210108'),2),
                (CONVERT(date,'20210109'),2),
                (CONVERT(date,'20210110'),3),
                (CONVERT(date,'20210111'),3))V([Date],[Group])) --GROUP is a reserved keyword, and should not be used for object names
SELECT [Date],
       [Group],--GROUP is a reserved keyword, and should not be used for object names
       SUM(Increment) OVER (PARTITION BY [Group] ORDER BY [Date] --GROUP is a reserved keyword, and should not be used for object names
                            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Iteration
FROM Lags
ORDER BY [Date];
```